# Form submits on enter key in text area instead of newline

Tags: jquery, html

I am having a simple textarea when I press enter my form is submitted. I want a new line in textarea rather than submission.

```
<textarea rows="4" asp-for="@Model.BusinessDescription"></textarea>
<script>
        $(function () {

            function disableF5(e) {

                if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    $("#nextButton").click();


                }
            }


        });
    </script>
```

Comment: <button type="submit"> to <button type="button">

Comment: Than how I am going to submit my form

Comment: on button click

Comment: @maxspan my question is that what do you want to really do on Enter when cursor is in `<textarea>` input field? Do you want cursor to go to next line ?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 13)
        $('#form').submit();
});

$('#form').on('submit', function() {
    console.log($("#txtarea").val());
    console.log("Form submitted successfully!!!");
    document.write("Form submitted successfully!!!");
    return false;
});
```

```css
#txtarea {
    padding: 6px;
    line-height: 1.618;
    font: 12px Verdana;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <textarea placeholder="Press Enter" id="txtarea" name="txtarea"></textarea>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Following code should solve the problem. Here I'm assuming two things.

1. If user press **only 'Enter' key then text area takes to new line** in text area.
2. If user presses **'Shift+Enter'** combination then form is submitted *(This is applicable when user is **inside textarea**)*.

```js
$('textarea').on('keydown', function(e) {
 if (e.shiftKey == true) //Checking if Shift is pressed
 {
    if (e.key == "Enter") 
        $('#form').submit();
 }
});

$('#form').on('submit', function() {
    console.log($("#txtarea").val());
    console.log($("#txtNormal").val());
    console.log("Form submitted successfully!!!");
    document.write("Form submitted successfully!!!");
    return false;
});
```

```css
#txtarea {
    padding: 6px;
    line-height: 1.618;
    font: 12px Verdana;
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<fieldset>
<legend>Form Submit v/s New Line</legend>
<ul>
<li>New Line in Text Area on <b>only Pressing Enter</b> and no form submit</li>
<li>Form Submit on <b>Shift+Enter</b></li>
</ul>
<form id="form">
<table>
<tr>
  <td>Singleline Input</td>
  <td>
    <input type="text" id="txtNormal" value="" placeholder="Enter Value" />&nbsp;<i>Form Submits on Pressing Enter</i>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>Text Area Input</td>
  <td><textarea placeholder="Press Enter" id="txtarea" name="txtarea" width="100%"></textarea>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td></td>
<td><i>Form Submits only on Pressing 'Shift+Enter' when in textarea input field</i></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td></td>
<td><input type="submit" value="submit" /></td>
</tr>
<table>

  
</form>
</fieldset>
```